# simple .htaccess rule wont work in httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache

Im trying to move a bunch of rewrite rules from a .htaccess file to a the apache config files, I get no errors and placed this within the VirtualHost section of the sites config file:

```
<Directory /var/www/da/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny

        allow from all

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteRule ^botswana/central-kalahari/$ /central-kalahari/ [R=301,L]

</Directory>
```

Comment: ... And what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite Rules placed in server config / virtual host context will start with leading slash -- that is one of the differences from .htaccess behaviour. Therefore use this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/botswana/central-kalahari/$ /central-kalahari/ [R=301,L]
```